# What's wrong with my manager disk size accuracy?

Tags: files, disk-management

[image]

I'm new to Elementary OS and after a week of using it I decided to check how much disk space I had used so far. I went to my SSD (Which used to be C:), right-clicked and looked at `properties`. I found the information I expected, though somewhat skewered. Now, please do correct me if I'm wrong... But does this say I have one-hundred-and-forty point seven Tera-bytes worth of files on my ~250GB SSD?

I like the OS so far... but this seems rather miraculous. What's causing this?

Comment: I remember seeing something about this before. This is it https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1595328 It's something to do with file loops causing miscalculations at high levels.